# Order Status Code (Status Category) Picklist values

Tags: fields, standard

In process builder, using formula entry criteria i have checked ISPICKVAL([Order.StatusCode], 'A') and i'm updating one picklist field in update actions. its worked fine that time and will moved to production.
After refreshing the sandbox, the same Process builder not worked in Production. Then I have changed ISPICKVAL([Order.StatusCode], 'Activated'). Its working fine now.

My question here is 
1. Is this get vary to production and Sandbox? OR
2. Is it due to org release version like spring 19 etc

I tried to found document but not getting relevant documents. Please can anyone give your comments if you have faced any issues like above. And if you find any relevant docs.

Comment: I believe it is a Standard field . Also, is picklist value (Activated) standard?

Comment: odd, for Order.StatusCode - label = `Activated` and API name = `A`

Comment: Peixoto, cropredy -- Thanks for your response. Few months back i have given "A" its worked. But now the same PB are not working. So i have replaced with "Activated". Its working fine now. But My question here is                                                        1. Is this get vary to production and Sandbox? OR                                                           2. Is it due to org release version like spring 19 etc